# Turning router wifi on/off

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I would like write a small Delphi app that turns wifi off at laptop start-up and on at shut-down. The router is a TP-Link TD8980.

I let my brother use my wifi for his Tablet when I am not using my PC.

Thanks

Comment: Poor brother! Anyway, good luck. If you have a question please ask.

Comment: The place to be asking this is the manufacturer of this router.

Comment: Just unscrew the wi-fi antennas when you come home and let him screw them back again when you're out

Answer (score 4):

Most routers do not expose an API for manipulating the router, except maybe uPNP for opening/closing server ports.  However, most routers do expose an HTTP/S-based control panel so users can access the router's settings.  So you could write an HTTP client app that logs in to the router's admin account and submits the necessary parameters to turn the WiFi on/off.  You will have to study the control panel's particular HTML to know what URL to submit to, and what values to send it.

Comment: I also think he can install OpenWRT and control router via ssh/telnet